# How to return message in Resposne Body?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have to retuen the message "Data Added" in the api in ResponseBody
Create a api while enters student data
/newStudent

Request Body:

```
{
"name":"Shubham",
"rollno":22,
"studentid":1
}
```

Response:

```
{
"status":"OK",
"message":"Data Added"
}
```

---

```
@RequestMapping("/studentdata")
@ResponseBody
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom response class that looks like this:

```
class CustomResponse {
   private String status;
   private String message;
   // Constructor/Getters/Setters
}
```

Then in your controller return `ResponseEntity` for example:

```
CustomResponse response = new CustomResponse("OK", "Data Added");
return ResponseEntity.ok(response); // the ok will return HTTP Status 200
```

Or if you want another HttpStatus, then you can use for example:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.CREATED);
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Do i have to create class in controller package or create another one.

Comment: It depends on your code architecture, If you plan to use this custom class in other controllers then it's better to create it globally, for example in a package domain!

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should create a Response class which will hold status code and your custom message like the following class :

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Response {
  private String statusCode;
  private String statusMsg;
}
```

So in your controller where you post the object use ResponseEntity which can allow you to customize HTTP response methods. For example:

```
 @Autowired
 private StudentRepository studentRepository;

 @PostMapping("/newStudent")
 public ResponseEntity<Response> saveEmployee(@RequestBody Student 
  student){
    studentRepository.save(student);
    Response response = new Response();
    response.setStatusCode("200");
    response.setStatusMsg("Your message");
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(response);
}
```

Comment: I m using service instead of Repository

Comment: You can use your service in the controller instead of the repository, and then inject your repository bean at your service. What I did here is just a simple example to show you how the response will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to return custom object in response.

```
router.post("/newStudent", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, rollNo, studentId } = req.data;

  // POST data to DB
  const result = await AddStudentDataToDB({ name, rollNo, studentId });

  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'ok',
    message: 'Data Added'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/studentdata", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String message(@RequestBody String transaction) {
  String response = "";

  JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
  obj.put("status", "OK");
  obj.put("message", "Data Added");
  response = obj.toJSONString();
  
  return response;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me like this in Response class:

```java
public class Response {
    private String statusCode;
    private String statusMsg;

    public String getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(String statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public String getStatusMsg() {
        return statusMsg;
    }

    public void setStatusMsg(String statusMsg) {
        this.statusMsg = statusMsg;
    }
}
```

In controller:

```java
@PostMapping("/newStudent")
    public ResponseEntity<Response> saveStudent(@RequestBody Student student) {
        Student save = service.save(student);
        Response response = new Response();
        response.setStatusCode("200");
        response.setStatusMsg("Data Added");
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(response);
    }
```